# php javascript ajax passing variables from mysql form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that gets data from a database and displays the results as buttons with the appropriate names. When i add javascript onclick i can diaplay the data_id. This all works but i want to be able to save the data to the main page in a textfield but it doesnt show anything? What code do you need to see or is it because i am loading an external php file to load the data that it isnt posting it past. Its doing my head in, I will post what code you want, i already have but had no joy.

For instance if i have a textfield called 'testField1' in my main page and on the same page i am getting a list of data from forms and mysql and the end is kicking out

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" onclick="display()">
```

I want it to diplay that data in the main page 'testfield1' using the script

```
<script>
function display()
    {
        document.getElementById("textField1").value = "$product_name";
    }
</script>
```

the code online is www.cheekytransport.co.uk/show.php

Comment: You need to actually echo the variable, `value = "<?= $product_name; ?>";` (if short tags are enabled, or in newer vesion of PHP - otherwise `<?php echo ..`)

Comment: Ive tried that but its like its just totally empty, ok if i run like alert direct from button but not from script on main page?